# Why was the Kashmir issue not completely solved at the end of Bangladesh Liberation War of 1971?

Tags: india, pakistan

India, at that point, had won the war and could have taken over the entire Kashmir.

However, they agreed to make the issue a two-party negotiation only, thus barring intervention by third parties. Indira Gandhi could’ve taken the whole Kashmir, or if she wanted to be so gentlemanly, then why not solve the issue once and for all?

Also, USSR was backing India and had previously brokered peace between Ind and Pak in the 1965 war. Why could the problem not be solved and made a two-party affair? Why not partition Kashmir, or give it whole to one party or something like a final solution?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: I don't see how the issue would be solved by having India absorb a bigger part that *doesn't want to be part of India*.  The issue isn't that the Pakistani part wants to be in India, it is that the Indian part supposedly wants to be in Pakistan.  Or at least is not allowed a referendum.  And why would India have *given ground* on either of those 2 points, which might indeed have improved things, having just won a war???

Comment: Does it or does it not is not decided, half the Kashmir region, geographically larger one is Buddhist and Hindu, and I don’t know what makes u think they want to go to Pakistan, none of the Kashmiri majority wishes to go to either India or Pakistan, they want to be autonomous. Please don’t be stereotypical

Comment: The feel I'm starting to get here is that the OQ really wants to have a nice argument with historical figures about what they could have done better, but since they aren't around will settle for our users. We aren't a discussion board, and even if we wanted to be don't really have the tools for that kind of thing. The best we can really do for you is to relate what happened and what the documented rationale for it was. With that in mind, what *specifically* do you want to know about the history of the matter? Just why a partition was not made?

Comment: Are there no government records that explain the decision?  This seems like a question that there _should_ be evidence to answer.

Comment: I want to know the Conclusion and the situations that led to the Shimla Agreement. Where does partition come in? That’s stupid to bring partition here. What’s important is what was the final deal, what did each party get in the negotiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why was the Kashmir issue not completely solved at the end of Bangladesh Liberation War of 1971?

A [1948 UN resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution) ([Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_39#:%7E:text=United%20Nations%20Security%20Council%20Resolution%2039%2C%20adopted%20on%20January%2020,two%20members%20of%20the%20commission.)) on Kashmir says there should be a plebiscite or referendum regarding the determination of the fate of Kashmir, and this fate would be determined by none other than the Kashmiri population. 1971 war had nothing to do with this said referendum.

Also, India couldn't open a new front in Kashmir because of the risk of China's involvement which the USSR kept in check. Remember, China claimed a part of Kashmir called *Aksai Chin*, and the *Saksgram Vally* was delivered to China by Pakistan through a land swap agreement. Thereby China and Pakistan became allies after 1962.

There was also a complex equation in progress regarding superpowers. The USA did not favor the USSR having too much influence in the region.

> Why could the issue not be solved and made a two-party affair?

Kashmir issue **is** a two-party affair according to India. Pakistan wants it to make a multi-party affair which India opposes.

I wrote [an answer in politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76002/32479) regarding this.

> Why not partition Kashmir, or give it whole to one party or something like a final solution?

Pakistan wants a referendum, and no one, not even a superpower, can exclude Pakistan from this dispute.